# Выбрать только один объект в HQL вместо всего списка (Hibernate i18n)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

У меня есть таблицы `Product`, `Category`, `Translation`, `Language`. После ниже представленного HQL-запроса, у меня на странице отображаются несколько языков вместо одного.

Я понимаю, что я в HQL делаю запрос аля:
"найди объект `Products`, в который является из той категории и содержит тот язык."

Но мне требуется "Найди объект `Product` с такой-то категорией и отобрази язык категории - `ru`".

вот визуализация таблиц с @OneToMany:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой HQL-код:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRESTRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
    List<Product> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT prod FROM Product as prod left join prod.category as trans where prod.category.defaultName = ?1 and trans.language.code like ?2")
    List<Product> findProductsByCategoryName(String category, String language);
}
```

А вот как выводится на экран:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Оффтоп:*** Ответ нашел в ответе, написанным в 2010 году(!!) и при том не связанным с моим вопросом.

Для решения моей проблемы, надо просто использовать `left join fetch`.

В итоге, вот код к моему варианту реализации i18n (Internationalization) с помощью HQL и JPA:

```java
@Query("SELECT prod FROM Product as prod " +
            "left join fetch prod.category as cat " +
            "left join fetch cat.translations as trans " +
            "where cat.defaultName = ?1 and trans.language.code = ?2")
List<Product> findProductsByCategoryName(String category, String language);
```

[image]
[image]

#### UPDATE 1

При работе с несколькими таблицами выпадала ошибка `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple Bags: [...]`

Решается она просто: Нужно заменить по максимому все `List<>` на `Set<>`. Пересоздавать таблицы не надо. Просто перезапустите код)

Ссылка на описание ошибки и ее решении - [ссылка](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-avoid-hibernates-multiplebagfetchexception/)